# Transmit parameter to the inner-most call of a composed function

Tags: python, functional-programming

I'm building a data pipelining tool and want to be able to compile a series of functions together.

All the functions act on an iterable, and pass an iterable as a yielded value.

So if `f(x)` filters, and `g(x)` edits, and `h(x)` generates a random value, then I want to be able to compose combinations of these so I can call `f(g(h(x)))` or `h(f(g(x)))` as per requirements.

I'd like to be able to prepare these compositions (they have different parameter signatures beyond the initial iterable) before knowing what `x` is going to be.

To complicate matters, `f`, `g` and `h`, while sharing the iterable parameter that they both consume and emit, they have different parameter signatures.

For convenience, I can wrap these parameters up in a `partial` statement to hide the messy parameters - but next I want to compose a series of functions as per the `f(g(h(x)))` example - the idea being that I want to shoe-horn a particular `x` iterable at runtime.

I'm finding that having `partial`'ed the functions, subsequently nesting them means I can't access that deepest parameter - and I'm getting errors like `AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'keywords'`.

In other words, is there a way to chain or nest functions in a way that allows you to defer specifying a parameter required by the innermost function at runtime?

e.g. The following works fine:

```
data_source = [ OrderedDict({"id" : "1", "name" : "Tom", "sync" : "a"}),
            OrderedDict({"id" : "2", "name" : "Steve", "sync" : "a"}),
            OrderedDict({"id" : "3", "name" : "Ulrich", "sync" : "b"}),
            OrderedDict({"id" : "4", "name" : "Victor", "sync" : "b"}),
            OrderedDict({"id" : "5", "name" : "Wolfgang", "sync" : "c"}),
            OrderedDict({"id" : "6", "name" : "Xavier", "sync" : "c"}),
            OrderedDict({"id" : "7", "name" : "Yves", "sync" : "c"}),
            OrderedDict({"id" : "8", "name" : "Zaphod", "sync" : "d"}),
           OrderedDict({"id" : "9", "name" : "Albert", "sync" : "d"})]


def f(x, filt):
    for content in x:
        if content['name']==filt:
            print ("test")
        yield content

def g(x,old, new):
    for content in x:
        if content["name"]==old:
            content["name"]=new
        yield content

def h(x, which):
    for content in x:
        if random.random()>0.5:
            content[which]=random.randint(0,100)
        yield content



p_f = partial(f, filt="Albert")
p_g = partial(g, old="Yves", new="Yeti")
p_h = partial(h, which='id')
iterator=(d for d in data_source)
for result in p_f(p_g(p_h(iterator))):
    print (result)
```

Which outputs:

```
OrderedDict([('id', '1'), ('name', 'Tom'), ('sync', 'a')])
OrderedDict([('id', 57), ('name', 'Steve'), ('sync', 'a')])
OrderedDict([('id', '3'), ('name', 'Ulrich'), ('sync', 'b')])
OrderedDict([('id', '4'), ('name', 'Victor'), ('sync', 'b')])
OrderedDict([('id', 33), ('name', 'Wolfgang'), ('sync', 'c')])
OrderedDict([('id', '6'), ('name', 'Xavier'), ('sync', 'c')])
OrderedDict([('id', 83), ('name', 'Yeti'), ('sync', 'c')])
OrderedDict([('id', '8'), ('name', 'Zaphod'), ('sync', 'd')])
test
OrderedDict([('id', '9'), ('name', 'Albert'), ('sync', 'd')])
```

But I want to be able to compose that function early - and bind the iterator of the composed function later.

Something like:

```
p_compiled = p_f(p_g(p_h))
for result in p_compiled(iterator):
    print (result)
```

But when I do this, I get `TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable`.

Comment: Is it possible to do `p_compiled = lambda i: p_f(p_g(p_h(i)))` and then use it like `for result in p_compiled(iterator):` ?

Comment: Yes, of course, that's the most direct method. I like the method in @jwodder's answer because it's more condusive to building a factory - but this is the most in-line direct fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you just want a `compose()` function:

```
def compose(f, g):
    return lambda x: f(g(x))

p_compiled = compose(p_f, compose(p_g, p_h))
for result in p_compiled(iterator):
    print (result)
```

Comment: OK that works, but I have no idea how it works (or rather why this works, and not my earlier composition) Let me think about it overnight and get to grips with what's going on.

Comment: Your earlier composition never *called* `p_h`. It should have simply been `p_compiled = lambda itr: p_f(p_g(p_h(itr)))`.

Comment: Yes, I get this now - and between this and @Andrej Kesely's comment above, there's a clear couple of options.Thankyou.